# How do I establish ssh connection

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04

I've installed ansible on my master vm, created and copied my key to my worker vm, but I'm unable to establish connection with the worker vm. When I try, I don't get any error message; it just stalls. I'm using ubuntu 18 on gcp.

```
root@mastervm-project:~# ssh ubuntu@10.128.0.11
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no firewall rule that allows ingress on 22 on your target instance.

I just reproduced. This will do the job:

**Step 1:**
Add a network tag on your VMs (`allow-ssh` in my example)
[image]

**Step 2:**
Go to VPC-FirewallRules and create a firewall rule that allows Ingress traffic incoming from instances that have the `allow-ssh` tag targeting other instances that have the same tag assigned, on tcp 22

[image]

Of course this will allow ssh both ways, but I suppose this is not a problem. If you need it one way only, add a comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Thanks for taking the time to read this.